# Customizing the appearance of DataTable button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

Good day everyone.

I'm recently working with a web application using ASP.Net (MVC 4) and found a pretty impressive kind of HTML table which is by using Datatable.

I'm able to create default buttons inline with the search element of the said table but my problem is their appearance it very simple and I've been reading it's documentation but i cant find a way to change their appearance specifically their background-image.

Thanks in advance

Here is my code for the Table.

```
    <table id="exampledatatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer Code</th>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <th>Customer Type</th>
                <th>Industry Type</th>
                <th>Website</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Off Day 1</th>
                <th>Off Day 2</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>5421</td>
                <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UpdateCompany") |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCompany") |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Restore", "RestoreCompany")
                </td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

And here is my code for generating it buttons

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#exampledatatable').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'copyHtml5',
                        text: '<h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-                                              plus-circle fa-x5"></i> New</h4>',
                        titleAttr: 'Create New Record'
                    },  
                    {
                        extend: 'csvHtml5',
                        text: '<h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-x5"></i> Edit</h4>',
                        titleAttr: 'Edit Existing Record'
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'csvHtml5',
                        text: '<h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-x5"></i> Delete</h4>',
                        titleAttr: 'Delete Existing Record'
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        text: '<h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-reply-all fa-x5"></i> Restore</h4>',
                        titleAttr: 'Restore Deleted Record'
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        text: '<h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-x5"></i> Refresh</h4>',
                        titleAttr: 'Restore Deleted Record'
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        text: '<h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-print fa-x5"></i> Print</h4>',
                        titleAttr: 'Restore Deleted Record'
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        text: '<h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-x5"></i> Close</h4>',
                        titleAttr: 'Restore Deleted Record'
                    }
               ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the generated HTML code:

```
<div class="dt-buttons">
<a class="dt-button buttons-copy buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="exampledatatable" href="#" title="Create New Record">
    <span>
        <h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-x5"></i> New</h4>
    </span>
</a>
<a class="dt-button buttons-csv buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="exampledatatable" href="#" title="Edit Existing Record">
    <span>
        <h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-x5"></i> Edit</h4>
    </span>
</a>
<a class="dt-button buttons-csv buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="exampledatatable" href="#" title="Delete Existing Record">
    <span>
        <h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-x5"></i> Delete</h4>
    </span>
</a>
<a class="dt-button buttons-pdf buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="exampledatatable" href="#" title="Restore Deleted Record">
    <span>
        <h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-reply-all fa-x5"></i> Restore</h4>
    </span>
</a>
<a class="dt-button buttons-pdf buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="exampledatatable" href="#" title="Restore Deleted Record">
    <span>
        <h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-x5"></i> Refresh</h4>
    </span>
</a>
<a class="dt-button buttons-pdf buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="exampledatatable" href="#" title="Restore Deleted Record">
    <span>
        <h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-print fa-x5"></i> Print</h4>
    </span>
</a>
<a class="dt-button buttons-pdf buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="exampledatatable" href="#" title="Restore Deleted Record">
    <span>
        <h4 style="font-size: 13px;"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-x5"></i> Close</h4>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Use use css to style it to look however you want.

Comment: Thanks for complying. But how can i reference the buttons on CSS since it is created using jquery? sorry for noobness

Comment: You need to show your code - how are you generating the buttons and what html does that generate. (you could just give the buttons a class name for example, or select them using `#mytable td button { // add style rules }`)

Comment: I've already included my codes.

Comment: And what is the actual html generated by one of those buttons?

Comment: The image is irrelevant. You need to show the actual html that your code is generating for one of those buttons.

Comment: I found the generated html code by the use of developers tool on the browser.I think i know now what to do. Thanks to you.

but can i somehow set an id on that generated html so that the styles will be applied uniquely on each buttons?

Comment: I doubt it (you would need to refer to the docs). But you can always refer to them by their index using the `nth-child()` selector (I cant really help further unless you show the html)

Comment: I already added the generated html code

Comment: OK, so the plugin already adds a `class="dt-button"` so you can use (say) `.dt-button { background-color: yellow; }` to make them all yellow, followed by `dt-button:nth-child(2) { background-color: green; }` to override it and make the 2nd one green (and your css file needs to loaded after the plugin's css file)

Comment: it did'nt work. how can i locate the plugin's css file?

Comment: You should not be editing the plugins css file. You should be creating your own css file that adds additional style rules

Comment: ahh. Ok. so what should come first?

Comment: Your css file needs to loaded after the plugin's css file.

Comment: I did it. thanks to your help :D

but can i have another question for you? is it possible to change the dt-buttons into image buttons?

Comment: I doubt it, unless you were to use javascript/jquery to create new elements and hide the existing ones (and the new ones would probably need to trigger the events on the hidden ones).

Comment: never mind my last question. :D thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 25):

it's more easy to use the the classname attribute

https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.className

Example:

```
$('#table2excel').DataTable({
paging: false,
"info": false,
searching: false,
dom: 'Bfrtip',
buttons: [
    { extend: 'copy', className: 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate' },
    { extend: 'csv', className: 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-save-file' },
    { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt' },
    { extend: 'pdf', className: 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-file' },
    { extend: 'print', className: 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-print' }
]
```

});

using bootstrap icons and style:

- http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: How to change ```className: 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-print'``` into ```className: 'btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-print'``` to change the button color?

Comment: This adds classes specified, however does not remove `dt-button` class, and hence style does not change to bootstrap class style.

Answer (score 13):

You can use jquery with this code :

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: ['print', 'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'csvHtml5', 'pdfHtml5'],
        initComplete: function () {
            var btns = $('.dt-button');
            btns.addClass('btn btn-success btn-sm');
            btns.removeClass('dt-button');

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see here as answer. I used Font Awesome (4.7):

```
  var table = $(#myTable).DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [{
        text: '<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> New',
        className: 'btn btn-success'
      }],
      initComplete: function() { 
        var btns = $('.dt-button');
        btns.removeClass('dt-button');
      },
  })
```

And link

```
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 1):

All your "buttons" have a style rule called .`dt-button` you can use a bit of jQuery to loop through all the elements which have this style rule and if they meet a specific criteria append an image to them:

```
$('.dt-button').each(function (i, obj) {

    var h4 = $(this).find("h4");

    var text = $(h4).text().trim();

    if (text == "New") {
        var image = "<img src='http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg' style='width:30px;height:30px;' />"
        $(this).append(image);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Width Jquery, After you call the buttons.
Something like this:

```
           $('#tabela_trab').DataTable( {
            "paging":   false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copyHtml5',
                'excelHtml5',
                'csvHtml5',
                'pdfHtml5'
            ]                 
        } );
      $(".buttons-html5").addClass("btn");
      $(".buttons-html5").addClass("btn-success");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [{
      "extend": 'excel',
      "text": 'Exportar Excel',
      'className': 'btn btn-success'
    },
    {
      "extend": 'print',
      "text": 'Imprimir',
      'className': 'btn btn-info'
    }
  ],
  initComplete: function() {
    var btns = $('.dt-button');
    btns.removeClass('dt-button');
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style the existing classes `.buttons-{name}` for the buttons. This is an example for the excel button:

```
.buttons-excel {
  left: 10%;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```